# PHP how to store words of a sentence into a string without explode

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, explode

I'm making a php tag script for my website.
I have completed the code, but I'm afraid my code is too long.

Can my code be more simple and short?

```
<?php
    include("admin/apps/site-settings.php"); // database connection
    $albumq = mysql_query("select * from albums order by rand() limit 20");
    while($album = mysql_fetch_array($albumq)){
    $name_a = str_replace("&apos;s","",$album['name']);
    $name_b = str_replace("&quot;","",$name_a);
    $name_c = str_word_count($name_b, 1);
?>
<?php if(!empty($name_c[0])){?>
    <a href="search-<?php echo $name_c[0];?>.html">
        <div class="tag">
            <?php echo $name_c[0];?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
<?php if(!empty($name_c[1])){?>
    <a href="search-<?php echo $name_c[1];?>.html">
        <div class="tag">
            <?php echo $name_c[1];?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
<?php if(!empty($name_c[2])){?>
    <a href="search-<?php echo $name_c[2];?>.html">
        <div class="tag">
            <?php echo $name_c[2];?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
<?php if(!empty($name_c[3])){?>
    <a href="search-<?php echo $name_c[3];?>.html">
        <div class="tag">
            <?php echo $name_c[3];?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
<?php if(!empty($name_c[4])){?>
    <a href="search-<?php echo $name_c[4];?>.html">
        <div class="tag">
            <?php echo $name_c[4];?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
<?php if(!empty($name_c[5])){?>
    <a href="search-<?php echo $name_c[5];?>.html">
        <div class="tag">
            <?php echo $name_c[5];?>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }?>
```

Output in the website:

[image: Output]

I'm running it on localhost so I can't provide a link at the moment.

Comment: Learn how to use foreach loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: let me know if my answer worked for you

Comment: Use for loop for do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include("admin/apps/site-settings.php"); // database connection
$albumq = mysql_query("select * from albums order by rand() limit 20");
while($album = mysql_fetch_array($albumq)){
    $name_a = str_replace("&apos;s","",$album['name']);
    $name_b = str_replace("&quot;","",$name_a);
    $name_c = str_word_count($name_b, 1);

    foreach ($name_c as $value)
    {
        if (!empty($value))
        {
            echo "
            <a href='search-{$value}.html'>
                <div class='tag'>
                    {$value}
                </div>
            </a>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and it's simple thanks a lot. I should learn to use foreach.

Comment: @PraneethMadushan no problem :). If my answer worked for you, please accept it (with a green checkmark) so that future users/readers know it worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

Use **foreach** loop for same , use like

```
if(count($name_c) > 0)
{
    foreach($name_c as $name)
    {
        ?>
        <a href="search-<?php echo $name; ?>.html">
            <div class="tag">
                <?php echo $name; ?>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not DV, but the answer in the top is clean.